# How do I swap 2 digits in an input given by the user?

Tags: python

```
# Read an integer:
a = input()
#Now swap it...
a[0] = a[1]
a[1] = a[0]
```

As you can see I am trying to change the value and trying to swap it..

```
print(a)
```

...and then i print it out. But I am getting an error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

For example, if my input is `79` I want the result to be `97`. Can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Strings are *immutable*, you cannot assign to characters by index. Search for your error message, there are lots of hits that will help you out.

Comment: Do you expect the input to be two digits? If it can be more than two digits, which ones do you want to swap?

Comment: If the code worked it would still be broken: you're losing `a[0]`.

Comment: You need to introduce a new variable, to which you could assign something like: `s2 = str(int(s))[::-1]`. Casting to make sure that the input was an integer (although it does not ensure everything, e.g. that it has two digits only)

Comment: you can use ```a=a[1]+a[0]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = input()
a = str(a)
result = int(a[-1: : -1])
print(result)
```

Output: ( a = 34 )

```
43
```

Comment: Note that there is no need to specify the starting index; ``[::-1]`` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question simple thing you can do. As above comment string is not iterable while you as input. You need to convert to `list` to access by index. For swap you need to use temporary variable, so i used `temp` as variable to swap.

```
a = list(input())
#Now swap it...

print(a)
temp = a[0]
a[0] = a[1]

a[1] = temp

print(a)
print("".join(a))
```

Comment: I actually don't now what temp is....(I am just a beginner)

Comment: For swap you need to use temporary variable, so i used temp as variable to swap.

Comment: Okay so,temp means temporary.....        Thank you